# Очередь(Добавление элементов)

Tags: c++, очередь

Нужно создать функцию, добавление элементов в очередь, выводится ошибка:"Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменение левосторонним значением"
Моя функция, которую я пытался создать:

```
void add(int* integer) {
    current = new queue;
    current->value = integer;
    current->next = NULL;
    if (last == NULL) {
        head = current;
    }
    else {
        last->next = current;
        last = current;
    }
}
```

Структура очереди:

```
struct queue {
    int value[10];
    queue *next;
};
```

Comment: Ошибка выводится ссылаясь на строку: "current->value = integer;"

Comment: логично - слева массив, справа указатель на int. Хотя они и выглядят похоже, и даже иногда взаимозаменяемы, они не являются совместимыми типами. Что именно залетает в add в качестве аргумента?

Comment: в качестве аргумента должен залетать массив, но даже при такой записи(void add(int integer[])) ошибка никуда не девается

Comment: и где last? что-то его нигде не видно

Comment: да и current тоже не объявлялся. Такое ощущение, что ф-цию добавления вы взяли из другого места, а не написали под вашу структуру

Comment: @NickPolica На всякий случай: Когда вы пишете массив как аргумент функции, компилятор заменяет его на указатель. Т.е. между `void add(int integer[])` и `void add(int *integer)` нет абсолютно никакой разницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выделили память в структуре под массив, и пытаетесь константный адрес перезаписать другим.

```
struct queue {
    int value[10]; // память уже выделена, при вызове new queue 
    queue *next;
};
```

Вам необходимо поставить вместо массива указатель в структуру, или копировать память в массив в структуре.

Так же вы можете перегрузить один из операторов присваивания/копирования, для того что бы при присваивании массива стурктуре, в структуру копировались данные.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, можете сказать, где можно получше ознакомится с такими структурами данных как стек, очередь и все в этом роде?

Comment: К сожалению, я вам не могу ничего порекомендовать из перечисленного вами, но вам стоит почитать о константных полях/массивах в структурах, и/или классах.

Comment: @NickPolica вот неплохой курс, который познакомит вас с очередями, стеками, деревьями и некоторыми алгоритмами: https://courses.openedu.ru/courses/course-v1:ITMOUniversity+PADS+spring_2018/courseware/74c7c0fe149a484dbc9250ac4b7925a7/22ec7cbad38a40d08682f6cc513d57b8/

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

В элементе очереди у вас хранится десять интов. Вы должны реализовать присваивание не плюсом, а копированием памяти.

```
#include <string.h>
void add(int * integers) {
memcpy( & current->value, integers, sizeof(int)*10);
```